# Nant cannot build the c# .net project

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, reference, nant

I want to use `Nant` to Debug for my project.

It shows:

> Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Target(s) specified:
>   run
>
> [solution] Starting solution build. [solution] Building 'Project_1'
>   [Debug] ...  [solution]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(847,9):
>   Warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install
>   the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your
>   application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK
>   or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved
>   from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of
>   reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly
>   targeted for the framework you intend.
>
> [solution]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
>   Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "System.Data". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.  [solution]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
>   Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "System.Drawing". Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.  [solution]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
>   Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "System.XML". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.  [solution]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
>   Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "System.Xml.Linq". Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

I have installed the .NET Framework 4 client Profile and extend already.

How to solve it???

Comment: You haven't referenced the assemblies.

Comment: Plese check

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876946/net-4-0-build-server-reference-assemblies-warnings-msb3644][1]
 I Think it is th same problem. Regards.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876946/net-4-0-build-server-reference-assemblies-warnings-msb3644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to install Windows 7 and .NET 4 SDK,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Then you might try again.