# Can .NET 4.5 assemblies reference .NET 4.0 assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I'm thinking about using Awesomium.NET for a project I'm working on which is built with .NET 4.5. Awesomium.NET targets the .NET 4.0 Client Profile. Will it be OK to reference the 4.0 libraries from a 4.5 project?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. The library costs money, and the integration work is non-trivial. I figured this information should be readily available, and it wasn't. Now it is.

Comment: It is free for non-commercial use, so just testing it would fall under that category :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be fine, both .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 use CLR 4.

Comment: A .NET 4.5 assembly can't reference a .NET 2.0 assembly?

Comment: @CédricBignon: I would be surprised if it couldn't (as Romano says, I'm pretty sure .Net is downward compatible anyway), but I haven't tried it, either. Knowing they use the same CLR gives me a rosy glow, however. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In general, assemblies compiled in .NET 1.1 or later can be referenced in higher runtime (CLR) versions. However, you cannot reference an assembly compiled in 4.0 in runtime 3.0