# ionic2 with visual studio MSB3644 error when starting new project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

Am using visual studio 2015 but whenever i begin a new ion ionic2 project an error

```
MSB3644 The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found.
To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for 
 this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for 
which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved 
 from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. 
 Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

After a research on the error i found out [This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ee46c54-3781-40cb-9828-b3380f231ee9/build-tools-2015-update-3-build-server-error-msb3644-only-net-40?forum=msbuild)  and [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876946/net-4-0-build-server-reference-assemblies-warnings-msb3644) but am using windows 10 on a 32 bit computer with program files folder and without the program filesx86 folder

Am not using any server and also a newbie to visual studio

I have also checked and

```
 C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0. is there
```

I also found out you need to add

```
msbuild -p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.
```

But am not sure where am supposed to add it

Can someone help me on this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But am not sure where am supposed to add it

1. Please run "Msbuild Command Prompt for VS2015"
   [image]
2. Go to the folder of project
3. run the msbuild command

   msbuild -p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0"

[image]