# The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" were not found

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

When trying to compile a solution, I get the following build error:

> Error MSB3644 The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" were not found. To resolve this,
>   install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or
>   retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you
>   have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be
>   resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in
>   place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be
>   correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
>     C:\RPR\Dev\Libraries\Common\Common.csproj   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    1111

I've tried installing the .NET Framework 4.6.2 SDK, as well as the 4.6 Targeting Pack, however both error that I already have it installed. I also tried installing Visual Studio 2017 but it still gives the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen this problem go away when you install the 4.5.2 developer pack (i.e. not the 4.6.2, but the 4.5.2 developer pack).

Comment: I've had this problem with 4.8, for some reason my csproj files had `4.8.0` inside, which is not the same as `4.8` apparently.

Comment: For the real answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58850755/155077

Answer (score 131):

Windows -> Search -> Visual Studio Installer -> Modify -> Individual Components and check the right version

Comment: This is a clean solution as Visual Studio will list all the versions for you and shows what you currently have installed and will manage the download/install.

Comment: Tried all the solutions above and none worked.  This one did the job. Thanks

Comment: Mine is asking for v4.6.1 (reference assemblies) and it shows v4.6.1 (development tools) installed via the installer... still trying to figure out what's going on. CANCEL THAT: My issue was that none of the .NET framework was installed at all by default. Thank you.

Comment: This should seriously be the top answer!

Comment: This one is the best answer!

Comment: If the error asked you to install the developer version, in the individual list mark SDK version, the Targeting Pack did not solve the issue.

Comment: I had to do it through the installer and not the self installer ..

Comment: I needed to understand how to modify the individual components of Visual Studio. This is the answer I was looking for. upvoted - Thanks!

Comment: In visual studio 2019,
Tools -> get tools and features -> .NET Desktop environment

Comment: The list in individual components does not contain all, for example framework 4.5 that I need.

Answer (score 110):

It turns out that I had installed the .NET Framework v4.6.2, not the Developer Pack for 4.6.2. Doh!

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Comment: I installed Dev Pack 462 and still get the warning. Do I have to restart my machine?

Comment: i had to restart visual studio after installing, then all good

Comment: dead link. Is this one a replacement? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net462

Comment: 2024 and I did the same mistake. Download the DEVELOPER pack people! 

Answer (score 38):

**Starting May, 2019** you can build your project on net20 up to net48 (including ne461) any machine with at least MSBuild or the .NET Core SDK installed without the need of Developer Pack installed.

If .NET Core SDK installed in you machine, Add the nuget package [Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies/1.0.0-preview.2) to your project

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.2">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>     
    </ItemGroup>
```

The package include all ReferenceAssemblies starting net20 up to net48

These packages enable building .NET Framework projects on any machine with at least MSBuild or the .NET Core SDK installed  plus other scenarios.

For more details:
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases/reference-assemblies

Comment: Perfect, works <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net20' Or '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40' ">

Comment: @M. Hassan Whem I have setup your solution,Now I am getting this error `vbc : error BC2017: could not find library 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll' [/Sample.vbproj]`

Comment: What is dotnet SDK version installed, project framework?

Comment: Thank you, this is the only one that worked for me since I'm working with a v3.5 project and there is no Developer Pack for that version.

Comment: Add to what project? All of them?

Comment: This doesn't work for sqlproj or if the project is unloaded and wont load. take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109092

Comment: I checked RichyRoo's reference and the main answer solved it for me.

Comment: I have a .NET Framework 4.5, and adding the packageref as above does not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: @Ted, It works for me in net45. You may try to use its separate  version v4.5 here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net45

Answer (score 19):

Installing the 4.6.2 Developer Pack did not work for me.

I had to install [.NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48136)

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the exact same error when building except it was for ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1".

I downloaded the Developer pack for 4.7.1 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56119

The pack installed these programs on the target machine (my build server).

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 Targeting Pack (ENU)

When I tried building again, I didn't get the error anymore and the build succeeded.

Comment: Similar issue (build server error). Had the same error but for 4.7.1 and this solved it for me.

Comment: Ditto for 4.7.2.

Answer (score 7):

For 4.7.2 issue I have to go here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472

Install the Download .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack as displayed in the image to fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was using ubuntu and faced the same problem. Even after I've downloaded latest vscode and mono for ubuntu it was not working. Then I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/il36tn/vscode_with_unity_on_linux/g3zjp5j/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).
Basically if you've installed mono then go to settings and set

> "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always".

hope it fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the installed .net framework on your development machine, it must be the same as project file targeting. You need to install the .net framework which the project file targeting after that try again the errors and warnings will disappear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can find this omnisharp setting inside Visual Studio C# extensions settings and go to the botton.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download required SDK package with [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) , .net framework 4.6.2 developer pack [download-link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net462) and install. **Restart the server**, now build will be successful.

You can check dotnet version with `dotnet --info`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, (I'm embarrassed to admit) I had a website loaded as a project and forgot to set it to No Build.

Answer (score 0):

Install VS2019 and select Framework 4.x.x targeting packs. That helped me to sort this error.

Previous VS installers are hidden in here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently installed ***Unity*** on ***Ubuntu 22*** and intend to use ***VS Code*** for development, chances are you're reading this after you've tried a number of ways and none of them worked...

---

I was in the same situation and the following worked for me:

1. Uninstall *VS Code* **`C#` extension** (may need to remove all extensions associated with *C#*)
2. Reinstall **`mono` and `mono-msbuild`**

   1. `sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates`
   2. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF`
   3. `echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list`
   4. `sudo apt update`
   5. `sudo apt install mono-roslyn mono-complete mono-dbg msbuild`
3. Reinstall *VS Code* **`C#` extension**
4. Set `omnisharp.useModernNet` to `false` in *VS Code* **File / Preferences / Settings**
5. Restart *VS Code*

---

***Update***

And now, after another *Ubuntu* update, this solution stopped working ...

However, I found a simpler and cleaner solution!

In my case, all the previous steps were completed and I did not check, maybe some of them are no longer needed.

You need to install the [**Unity**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudiotoolsforunity.vstuc) and [**C# Dev Kit**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) extensions in *VS Code*.

Also you need to keep this requirements:

- **Unity 2021** or greater.
- Activated **C# Dev Kit** extension in Visual Studio Code.
- **.NET 7 SDK or greater**, the C# Dev Kit will install it if required.
- Visual Studio Editor Unity package **2.0.20** or greater.

---

Sources:

- https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/4347#issuecomment-1326793604
- https://gist.github.com/petergloor/39ba915d3a66d138448ed57be6fe93ca
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudiotoolsforunity.vstuc