# Is MonoDeveloper from Unity 2018.3.12f1 (latest) supporting .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, .net-framework-version

**This question is not a duplicate**

I am scripting in Unity using C# with the build in MonoDeveloper-Tool.
When I run the script I got the error message, that the assemblys for framework ".netframework, version=v4.7.1" has not been found. I looked it up on stackoverflow and only found this article:
[The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" were not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548780/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netframework-version-v4-6-2-were-not-f)

So I downloaded this version, but I can't install it, because I already have the latest version installed from .net framework, which is currently .NET Framework 4.7.2

**Questions:**

Is MonoDeveloper in "Unity 2018.3.12f1 Personal" not supporting this version?

Are there ways to upgrade it to make it work?

Or do I have to remove the .net-version, that I have and get an older one to make it work?

Comment: MonoDevelop has been deprecated in combination with Unity for some time now. If you keep having troubles with MonoDevelop I would suggest you try VisualStudio or Rider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are getting is ususally related to scripting backend setting in PlayerPreferences.

Here's a screenshot from 2017

[image]

and from 2019

[image]

It defaults to 3.5 for new projects, and you need to manually set it to 4.x, than pretty much all features from 4.7 work fine

Answer (score 0):

> Is MonoDeveloper in "Unity 2018.3.12f1 Personal" not supporting this version?

MonoDeveloper supports, but Unity doesn't.

> Are there ways to upgrade it to make it work?

Try install .net 4.6 with [Visual Studio Installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) or upgrade the Unity.