# Jenkins - build is failing randomly

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, .net-framework-version

I build my .net projects through Jenkins. There is one project, that fails very random with
this exception:

warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found.

I have VisualStudio 2012 installed on a build machine and I have other projects that
use .net 4.5 and they build without problems. Has anyone dealed with this?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730765/net-4-0-build-issues-on-ci-server ?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue in Configuration, more precise, I had to check "Restrict where this project can be run" and put master in there. Because if you don't do that, Jenkins will run on a different machine (slave) if it is configured that way.